# Python3 will not import file "apikey.py"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, openai-api

Note: I have seen the temporary policy on use of generative AI, but I believe that this post does not count as *use* of generative AI on Stack Overflow.

Essentially, I am trying to use Python 3 to create a ChatGPT prompt and response. But python keeps giving the error:

```
  File "/Users/goobl/code/ai_speech/gpt_generation.py", line 2, in <module>
    from apikey import APIKEY
ImportError: cannot import name 'APIKEY' from 'apikey' (/Users/goobl/code/ai_speech/apikey.py)
```

I did end up changing the code a little bit to import the whole file, but it just provided me with this error instead:

```
File "/Users/goobl/code/ai_speech/gpt_generation.py", line 3, in <module>
    openai.api_key = key.APIKEY
AttributeError: module 'apikey' has no attribute 'APIKEY'
```

The code to the file attempting to import the variable "APIKEY", gpt_generation.py, is here:

```
import openai
import apikey as key
openai.api_key = key.APIKEY

output_test = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo", 
  messages=[{"role": "user", "content": 
             "Name twenty different fruits. Thank you!"}]
)

# Print out the whole output dictionary
print(output_test)
```

And the code to the file I am trying to import, apikey.py, is here:

```
APIKEY = "my api key"
```

Edit: I forgot to save, as mentioned in a comment.

Comment: My guess is you have other files called `apikey.py` and it's picking up the wrong one.  Maybe `print(key.__file__)`?

Comment: Show us the contents of `/Users/goobl/code/ai_speech/apikey.py`.  Also, if you recently edited that file, make sure you **saved** it.